# How to play individual chunks of an audio only MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, audio, blob, mediarecorder, chunks

I am trying to create individual chunks of a MediaRecorder stream and be able to play each chunk individually as it is recording. To clarify my question I have a [sample website](https://student.sernie.com/)

[image: website image of chunks]

Here's the code, I create a block object whenever I receive the `dataavailable` event. This event is fired because I pass in a timesplit argument into `mediaRecorder.start(2000)` so that the event is fired after collecting 2 seconds of data.

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
let count = 0;

function Block(chunk, index) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "block";
  div.onclick = () => {
    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(chunk);
    const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
    audio.play();
  };
  div.innerText = index;
  container.append(div);
}

const recordAudio = async () => {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
    new Block(event.data, count);
    count += 1;
  });

  mediaRecorder.start(2000);
};

recordAudio();
```

Out of all the chunks, only the first chunk can be played. How to I play the other chunks?

**update 1**
I tried grouping the chunks together and I created a helper function to do that that you can try in the console.

If I group the first chunk and any other chunk, the audio becomes playable. For example, `play(3)` will create a blob of the first chunk (index 0) and the chunk at index 3.

[image: play function in console]

Here's the play function (`allChunks` is an array containing all the audio chunks)

```
const play = (idx) => {
  const audioBlob = new Blob([allChunks[0], allChunks[idx]]);
  const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
  const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
  audio.play();
};
```

I'm suspecting that the first audio chunk contains meta tags that if I added to the other audio chunks, I would be able to play them individually.

**Update 2**
To test out my theory to the above, when users click on a block I created a fileReader object so I can see the chunk data.

```
  div.onclick = () => {
    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(chunk);
    const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
    audio.play();

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(chunk);
    reader.onload = () => {
      console.log(reader.result);
    };
  };
```

The playable chunk and non-playable chunk looks like very similar base64 encoded strings.

[image]

Comment: Start multiple recorders if you want multiple files.

Comment: @songz I am going down this same path in an effort to create 1-second long video clips using the timeslice param with 0 jumps in-between, did you end up arriving at a solution?